# Mysql how to get exact day and time between two dates

Tags: mysql

I am passing date and time as input.

'2015-01-12 10:30:00' and '2015-01-13 11:30:00' like this.
we can find the days, hours, minuets, seconds etc between the timestamps. by using the FUNCTION called **timestampdiff()**.

I tried this query.

`SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2015-01-12 10:30:00','2015-01-13 11:30:00')/24 FROM DUAL`

but it gives me output like **1.04**.

My requirement is exact day and hours between that two dates.

Ex:
 '2015-01-12 10:30:00' and '2015-01-13 11:30:00' for this

**OUTPUT :** 
1 day and 1 hrs.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call that function twice. To have the result with the sentence you want, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,'2015-01-12 10:30:00', '2015-01-13 11:30:00'), 
  " day(s) and ",
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2015-01-12 10:30:00', '2015-01-13 11:30:00') % 24, 
  " hour(s)");
```

If you also want month or minute interval, just add one more function call and the appropriate modulo number

Comment: this will give the day, but i will not give the exact hours. for example 25 hours means, we can say that as 1 day and 1 hour.

Comment: so, you can use the modulo function, or round( /24) of it. I m editing my answer for this.

Comment: you're welcome. By the way, you can validate an answer to questions you asked by clicking on the check at the left of the answer. This way other people with the same problem will easily see the correct answer.

Comment: @Aashick yes it will give the exact hours. the first part handle the days, and there is never more than 24 hours between 2 days ^^

Answer (score 0):

This query can give you required output

```
SELECT CONCAT(
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,'2015-01-12 10:30:00', '2015-01-13 11:30:00'),
"day(s) and ",
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2015-01-12 10:30:00', '2015-01-13 11:30:00') % 24,
" hour(s)");
```

Comment: @Aashick use mod 24 operation to convert hour in proper way